# Are top links broken for everyone

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When I get here from SO by folliwing a new comment link, and sometimes from the all sites list -

The set of links at the top that should show My Name | review | chat | meta | about | faq have been missing for a couple days.

Not sure it is just me, or if it is happening to everone.

There is an older question https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/what-is-up-with-the-top-bar-disappearing about it, but no resolution.  It only seems to be happening at SciFi, not at any of the other sites I visit.

**Edit**
Running Windows 7 and IE 8,  I checked with FF and it seems to be working fine. So this would be a browser issues.  Appoligies for not checking FF first.

From SO

[image]

To SciFi

[image]

**Edit April 22, 2013**
Adding a message (at SciFi) causes the problem for me.  I am currently able to recreate on demand.

Image shows the message I get just as the links go away.

**Compatibility View**
A problem displaying stackexchange.com caused Internet Explorer to refresh the webpage using Compatibility View.

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me in FF PC and Mac. What os/browser are you running?

Comment: Just tried it in IE8 on XP and it shows up for me both when I load the page normally and when I navigate via inbox link.

Comment: It started working for me also, I notice that when I opened the link in a new tab or new window, it was displaying properly.  About the same time it started working as link in the same tab.  If no-one else did anything then presumably whatever causes issues in EI can be corrected by just opening in a new window, must clear something. But I know I opened a link in new window from SciFi and it only showed in the new window, it might be the open in new tab that causes the fix.  If we can't recreate the issue (which I am not seeing now) we can't know for sure.

Comment: Now it has started miss behaiving again, even opening in a new window from SO is a problem.  Will post screen shots

Comment: Good from Chrome as well, if we're looking to eliminate browsers.

Comment: Could it be one of your addons/extensions for that browser?

Comment: I am not aware of any addon/extensions on the browser.  The effect has been transient.  Currently on a different PC and just tried it with both EI and FF not seeing the problem.

Comment: Update: I am on the orginal PC today, I have linked in several times today, without a problem. **EDIT** And then it broke, right after leaving this message, closed and re-opened the IE window and that fixed the problem

Comment: Test does adding comment cause the problem?  Yes it does, updating question with new screen shot.

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006845/what-specific-things-cause-ie8-to-trigger-compatibility-mode  where there is a discusion on compatibility view

Comment: @JamesJenkins - are you only seeing this in compatibility view? If so, that's emulating a much older version of IE than we support.

Comment: @Nick - Now that I know what is causing it, I believe it is limited to compatibility view.  - Also of note; being in compatibility view on SO does not cause the problem, it is limited to SciFi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to wrap this up... as Nick noted in the comments, we don't support compatibility view.